# How would I programmatically store and apply a selection in a JTable

Tags: java, jtable

I have a program that creates a huge jtable with CellSelection enabled to copy to clipboard. I also have an Action that copies the complete table.

It does so by:

```
correspondentTable.selectAll();
// then copy
correspondentTable.clearSelection();
```

It would be very nice if after that the "complex" selection would be restored after this action.

So far I found `table.changeselection(row, col, toggle, extend)` but I was wondering if there is a "more elegant" way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for individual cells, you could iterate over the table cells and check them using `isCellSelected`. Actually, I see no "more elegant" solution than that.

It should be possible to limit the range you need to check:

Use `getSelectedRow()` to get the minimum index, `getSelectedRows()` gets you all indices. There are similar functions for columns.

You store these values somewhere and use `changeSelection` to restore the selection.

Edit: You can get the column model (`getColumnModel()`) and the selection model (`getSelectionModel()`), which store the selection value. If you can copy them, you could reapply there values afterwards.

Comment: didn't want to hear. But seems true.